# How do you disable CRT Exceptions?

Tags: exception, visual-c++, g++, crt

I don't use exception handling in any of my libraries or applications. Everything is built with Exception handling off and Windows applications using MS Visual Studio are linked with nothrownew.obj.  The code handles any failures itself.    The fact that the CRT is out behind my back throwing exceptions and terminating the program instead of returning an error result is a problem.

For example, this crashed when provided a drive letter that no longer existed instead of just returning the errcode.

```
if (_tgetdcwd(driveltr ? DriveLtrToDOSDriveNum(driveltr) : 0, dirout, diroutbufsize)==NULL) {
    errcode=GetErrorFromErrno();
}
```

For now on Windows I've used the `_set_invalid_parameter_handler()` to prevent the nasty issue above.  Goes something like this:

```
void invalid_parameter_function(const wchar_t * expression, const wchar_t * function, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line, uintptr_t pReserved)
{

}

int _tmain(int argc, const TCHAR *argv[])
{
  _set_invalid_parameter_handler(invalid_parameter_function);
}
```

Is there a way to ensure the CRT doesn't throw exceptions for both MS Visual Studio 2017 and the CRT used with g++? If not and must setup a handler like I did above for Windows, does g++ have one?

TIA!!